# Angular2-Visual Studio 2013 - when pressed Ctrl+K+D, formatting changes to lowercase issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, angular

Note: *This issue doesn't belong to **Angular2** directly, but if someone who uses **Angular2** with **vs13** might help*.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> in **visual studio 2013**, it changes ***`HTML's or Angular2's directives/markup written in camelcase to lowercase`*** and so  obviously **angular2** throws errors.

eg. ***`[ngFormModel] => [ngformmodel]`***

I have noticed, sometimes without pressing **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>**, it happens.

How to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because it isn't aware of what Angular2 is, **you need to update to Visual Studio 2015** and Ctrl-K-D will work. This is the same as using an older version of MVC with 2013, Ctrl-K-D will have similar issues.